# Is there a good reason to initialize a static variable on every call to the function where it is defined?

Tags: c

A colleague is doing some code review, and he is seeing many static variable declarations similar to the following:

```
void someFunc(){

   static int foo;
   static int bar;
   static int baz;

   foo = 0;
   bar = 0;
   baz = 0;

   /* 
       rest of the function code goes here
   */

}
```

Our question is,
Are the programmers who wrote this code simply unclear on the concept of a static variable,
or is there some clever reason to do this on purpose?

If it makes any difference, the environment is an embedded microcontroller and the compiler is GCC.

Comment: When declaring as static, it avoids storing the variable in stack. So minimizing stack size could also be a reason..

Comment: If they did it on purpose, e.g., to reduce stack usage, then they should have explained that in a comment.

Answer (score 13):

If it were not an embedded system, you would probably be correct: I would bet that the programmers were unclear on the concept of the static, and must have meant to write this:

```
static int foo = 0;
static int bar = 0;
static int baz = 0;
```

However, in an embedded system they could have used `static` to avoid allocating the variables in the automatic storage (i.e. on the stack). This could save a few CPU cycles, because the address of the static variable would be "baked into" the binary code of the compiled method.

Comment: It also saves stack space, which I think is probably the more important point. It will save memory overall, if the function is recursive (though that will make using static variables tricky). If the stack size is very limited, it might be necessary to avoid stack overflow.

Comment: @morningstar a very good comment to very good answer to a very good question.

Comment: recursive function calls using static variables?! there had better be a very good reasons

Comment: An iteration counter might be a use for a static variable in a recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

In this context the static memory is allocated only once.  The problem with this code is the initialization.  If it's being reset at every execution, these variables should exist on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the function as it is, undermines the `static` benefits. The main 2 reasons for using `static` are:

1. Having a variable that maintains it's value between calls to the same function
2. Avoid allocating memory on the stack

@dasblinkenlight answer's pertains to the 2nd option, however there is nobody in embedded programming who would waste unrecoverable memory in order to save 24 bytes (assuming that `int` is 32 bytes on your architecture) on the stack. The reason is that the compiler is going to manipulate the stack pointer coming in to the function regardless, and therefore there is nothing to be save (in terms of cycles) from not having it push the SP another 24 bytes.

Keeping that in mind, we are left with the option that the user wanted to maintain some information regarding `foo`, `bar` and `baz` between calls. If this is also not the case, what you are looking at is bad programming.

Comment: While the tradeoff between stack and the data segment makes little sense in most 32-bit micros, it could make sense in a very limited resource case such as many PIC processors or AVR processors. The smallest PICs have a very shallow hardware call stack and only a few hundred bytes of RAM total. Of course, most code for that limited an environment simply uses global variables. There are even some ARM cores in system on a chip packages with very small RAM (and pin count) too.

Comment: @levengli I assume you mean 32 bits, not 32 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

static benefits.  are:

Having a variable that maintains it's value between calls to the same function
Avoid allocating memory on the stack